# unexpected output from the init value and from the main function

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, init

I am trying to do the binary tree inversion in Python. I did in the following way.

```
class Node:
   def __init__(self, data):
      self.left = None
      self.right = None
      self.data = data
      print(self.left)
      print(self.right)
          

   def PrintTree ( self ) :
       if self.left :
           self.left.PrintTree ()
       print ( self.data, end= ' ' ) ,
       if self.right :
           self.right.PrintTree ()

class Solution:
    '''
    Function to invert the tree
    '''
    def invertTree(self, root):
       if root == None:
           return
       root.left, root.right = self.invertTree(root.right),self.invertTree(root.left)
       return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    Tree = Node(10)
   
    Tree.left = Node(20)
    print(Tree.left.data)
    Tree.right = Node(30)
    print(Tree.right.data)
    Tree.left.left = Node(40)
    Tree.right.right = Node(50)
    print('Initial Tree :',end = ' ' )
    Tree.PrintTree()
    Solution().invertTree(root=Tree)
    print('\nInverted Tree :', end=' ')
    Tree.PrintTree()
```

The thing that is not coming as expected by me is when I print the `self.left` and `self.right` they are coming as None, but when I print it in the main function, they give the values (eg: `Tree.left.data` or `Tree.left.data`). The result is as follows:

```
None
None
None
None
20
None
None
30
None
None
None
None
```

If we are getting None, then what is the point of assigning tree.left and tree.right to a value??

Comment: There are too many prints in the code to know what is going on. Try printing only from `PrintTree`. If it still does not work, [edit] the question so that it forms a [mcve]

Comment: I am just comparing the print in the init function and main function.

Comment: The `print()`s in `__init__()` cannot possibly produce anything other than two Nones, because you *just initialized those two attributes to None*.

Answer (score 0):

add this to PrintTree function:

```
print (self.data) #Missing
```

And also remove prints on **init**